# How to find the top left corner of an arbitrary convex quadrilateral?

Tags: geometry

I have 4 arbitrary points in 2D space. They are in an array, where they are guaranteed to be ordered counter-clockwise in relation to each other. How do I tell which of the points is the top left one?

[image: examples]

Comment: Obviously there is no unique answer in the arbitrary case.  What is the answer for this quadrilateral?  (-1,0), (0,-1), (1,0), (0,1)

Comment: Why do you need a "top left corner"? Could you use the leftmost point instead?

Answer (score 1):

Two vertices belong to the set **LEFT**, and two to the set **TOP** (excepting colinear axial perpendicularites - but we can assume all the coordinate components are piecewise-distinct).

You want the intersection vertex, if it exists, which is not always the case (e.g. (1,0), (0,1), (10,9), (9,10)), in which case there is no TL coordinate.

We can make progress with the highest element of the **LEFT** set, or the leftmost element of the **TOP** set, which leaves two choices.

Alternatively, make an arbitrary 'north', and read the vertices anti-clockwise as N: TL, BL, BR, TR.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my algorithm: name the vertices $A, B, C, D$ where $A$ is the leftmost and they are ordered clockwise (if there are several leftmost, choose the topmost of them to be $A$). Now let $X$ be the topmost of all the points. If $X$ is $A$ or $B$, then $TL=A$. If $X$ is $C$ or $D$ then $TL=B$.

Answer (score 0):

Can we agree that the top left corner is the first one met by a "sweeping line" with a $45°$ slope coming from above ?

Therefore, as the equation of such a line is $y-x=m$, it suffices to test the four quantities $y_k-x_k \ (k=1\cdots 4)$ for the four coordinates $(x_k,y_k)$ of the vertices. The highest value gives the winner vertex... of course with a possible "tie" if one of the sides has itself a $45°$ slope.

Comment: "of course with a possible "tie" if one of the sides has itself a 45° slope." In the case of the "tie" one can use the convention that by "top-left" the top one wins, and by "left-top" the left one does. :)

Comment: So $x+y$ is maximal for top-right. But this can declare a point both TL and TR, for example (0,10),(-1,0), (0,-1), (1,0).

Comment: @JMP Yes, indeed. This is why you have to tconsider  $\max (x_k-y_k) $ $\max (x_k+y_k) $ as a **definition/criteria** to which one can **refer** if any doubt...

Comment: That's what I thought, because your defn doesn't match with some of the examples.

Comment: Yes, but, let us come back to your 5th example (first line) compared to your 6th example ( I adhere to this 6th example) : it is very very disputable (very few "North" compared to the amount of "West"... But maybe you privilegized the North...)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing [the following algorithm](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2199683&p=12901520#post12901520):

1. Determine the point with the greatest y-value. Call it P. This is one of your upper corners.
2. Draw lines from P to both its neigbors. Take the endpoint of the line that has the shallower angle (closer to horizontal), and call it Q.
3. If P's x-value is less than Q's x-value, then P is your top left vertex and Q is top-right. If P's x is greater than Q's, exactly the opposite.

Of course, this doesn't cover all of the cases, but some are simply impossible to solve due to ambiguities, and require special treatment anyway. This algorithm correctly covers all the real world cases I tried so far, and thus is "good enough" for me. If someone can come up with a more robust algorithm, perhaps with provisions for detecing ambiguous cases, that would be much appreciated.